# How can i read data from pins of orange pi 4g iot and how can i write in "/system/bin/sh". how to fix "can't create pin: Read-only file system"

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors, orange-pi

### Orange pi 4g iot+ android 8.1= What about pins?

i'm beginner in android, please help me to overcome this problem:

i have **orange pi 4g iot and Android 8.1** on it (from the http://www.orangepi.org/downloadresources/)

so, from the manual i now **how to check status of pins** from **adb:**

> cat /sys/devices/virtual/misc/mtgpio/pin

, **but if i want to change it:**

> echo -wdout123 1 > pin

,**i have this**:

> /system/bin/sh: can't create pin: Read-only file system

**how can i fix it**?

i have already tried:

> mount -o rw,remount /system

But the **main question is** **how to receive data from sensors**(not just status),like nmea data or data from nfc sensor?

p.s i want to make **android app in android studio**, but i don't know how to recieve data from pins in app...
i tried android.things(don't support my orange), pi4j a bit (but failed, maybe because of i'm begginer) also i were googling a lot to find something similar with my project.

any help is welcome!